# queryselector shows wrong length while i search form tag

Tags: html, dom, find, selectors-api

> when i find "form tag" using querySelector from html it shows length 2.
>          instead show 1.
>
> querySelector return wrong length value.

Comment: And form has two fields, i guess? http://jsfiddle.net/anhnm8qf/ It seems that form children are returned.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('form').length - return right value, interesting... :)

Comment: yes form have two fields. and i am using querySelector